# Replace SYMBOL in file with SYMBOL in another file based on matching string

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am not the best scripter and have run into a issue which you might be able to guide me on.
I have two files.

(1) SYMBOL.txt (where 1st and 2nd column represent NAME and ID)

```
"UBA6"  "A0AVT1"
"NBAS"  "A2RRP1"
"GSAP"  "A4D1B5"
"GRID2IP"   "A4D2P6"
"TRAPPC13"  "A5PLN9"
```

(2) PAIR.txt (1st and 2nd column represent IDs)

```
A0AVT1  P62988
P06400  Q14186
Q14186  P28749
Q6NUQ1  A2RRP1
O43264  A2RRP1
```

I need to match `SYMBOL.txt` with `PAIR.txt` and substitute the `IDs` in `PAIR.txt` with NAMES from `SYMBOL.txt`.

(1) I have written a simple awk script that solves the purpose, but I **also** need to replace the `IDS` with `NA`that are not being matched at all (Actually I was not able to do that).

(2) I am getting the input file `PAIR.txt` modified as output, but I need a separate output file (say `LL` in this case).

The script I have written:

```
awk '{print $2 $1}' SYMBOL.txt \
    | sed 's/^/sed/g' \
    | sed 's/\""/\//g' \
    | sed 's/\"/\//g' \
    | sed 's/^sed/sed -i \"s/g' \
    | sed 's/$/g"/g' \
    | sed 's/$/ PAIR.txt/g' \
    | sh >LL
```

The sample output I need:

```
UBA6 NA
NA NA
NA NA
NA NBAS
```

Any Suggestions Please.

Comment: Do you know that `sed` accepts more than one command?

Comment: @choroba And so does `awk` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `sed` to write `sed`, which would execute a single `sed` command for each line in 'PAIR.txt', I think you'd be better off with a little more `awk`. Here's one way that uses an array to hold your NAME and IDs. It uses a ternary operation to swap out missing IDs with string "NA".

```
awk 'FNR==NR {

    gsub(/"/,"");
    a[$2]=$1;

    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {

        $i = ($i in a) ? a[$i] : "NA"
    }
}
1' SYMBOL.txt PAIR.txt
```

Results, using your input:

```
UBA6 NA
NA NA
NA NA
NA NBAS
NA NBAS
```